# Variable format specifier in C

Tags: c

I have a printf statement as follows:

```
printf("[%d] %d", i, n->data);
```

I'm trying to make the related code flexible so you can change the variable type of "n->data" depending on your need.  Is there a way to make the format specifier update depending on the variable type used?

I've tried including:

```
const char FS[2] = "%f";
```

when the variable is a float, then amending the printf statement to:

```
printf("[%d] "FS, i, n->data);
```

but this gets the following error, which I don't know how to resolve:

```
dLList.c:125:23: error: expected ')'
        printf("[%d] "FS, i, n->data);
                      ^
dLList.c:125:15: note: to match this '('
        printf("[%d] "FS, i, n->data);
              ^
1 error generated.
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Use `snprintf` to create a variable format specifier and pass the resulting string into `printf`.

Comment: @kaylum: does `printf` accept string variable as a control string?

Comment: @artm Yes, of course it does. Try it if you have any doubts.

Comment: can you show me an example, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `const char FS[2] = "%f";`, you may try to use macro like this:

`#define FS "%f"`

that would aggregate the control string format as you apparently want.

Comment: Would that change the format specified in printf statement

Comment: Yes it would as juxtaposed string literals form a single string constant

Comment: yeah I think the preprocessor would change the control string format in `"[%d] "FS`

Comment: Using this approach seems to result in the same error

Comment: It works for me. Remember to delete the line `const char FS[2] = "%f";`; and put  `#define FS "%f"` outside main(), then try it again.

Comment: Got it now! I had a `;` after the `"%f"` by mistake.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to make the format specifier update depending on the variable type used?

Yes, C11 has `_Generic`.  This allows code selection based on the type of the expression.  The selection is not evaluated at run-time, but at compile time, the type is determined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define print(X) printf(_Generic((X), \
    double: "%e\n", \
    int: "%i\n", \
    char *: "%s\n", \
    default: "TBD" \
) , X)

int main(void) {
  print(5.0);
  print(5);
  print("Five");
  print(1.0f);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
5.000000e+00
5
Five
TBD
```

Comment: +1, but be careful with the `default` case. If something else is given as an argument and the compiler isn't smart enough to see that there are not enough formats, this will crash at run time. Just leave out the `default` case and this will just not compile if there is another type. (Ah, and maybe also add a case for `char const*`)

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Agree work is needed for the default case - leaving out seems good.  Note: `const char *` invokes the `char *: "%s\n"` case, at least on my GCC

Comment: no it shouldn't, `char*` and `char const*` are incompatible types.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an enum and a lookup table for format strings.
Just make sure your struct that contains the data also contains a matching enum describing the type of data currently contained in the struct.

That way you can write a print function that accepts such a struct as an argument and prints its value using a correct format string for that type of data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum Format_
{
    /* Add/remove formats as needed. */
    SIGNED_DECIMAL_INT,
    UNSIGNED_DECIMAL_INT,
    DECIMAL_FLOATING_POINT,
    STRING,
    POINTER_ADDRESS,
    NUM_SUPPORTED_FORMATS
} Format;

static const char* formatStrings[NUM_SUPPORTED_FORMATS] =
{
    "%d\n", /* Add more complex format strings if needed. */
    "%u\n",
    "%f\n",
    "%s\n",
    "%p\n"
};

typedef struct Wrapper_
{
    Format format;
    float data;
} Wrapper;

void printData(const Wrapper *const wrapper)
{
    printf(formatStrings[wrapper->format], wrapper->data);
}

int main(void)
{
    Wrapper wrapper;

    wrapper.format = DECIMAL_FLOATING_POINT;
    wrapper.data = 12.345f;

    /* Prints 12.345000 */
    printData(&wrapper);

    return 0;
}
```